# Clark's formula - population density

Tags: php, math

I have a problem:

C. Clark's model of urban population densities indicating that population density varies with distance from the center of the city according to the equation Dx=D0e-bx where Dx is the population density at distance x from the center. D0 is the density at the center, e is the base of the natural logarithms, and b is a natural logarithm measuring the rate of change of density with distance.

[image]

How can I write this formula in php language?
Thanks!

What I have tried:

```
Dx = D/(x/b*b);
```

But I thinks this is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: i posted an answer, but i think nb wanted to say this is really straightforward, unless you missed some details (e.g. algorithm has to guess _b_). although he was a bit of an hater :)

Comment: We are not a code translation service, or a code writing service. YOU wire the code, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: @hummingBird - I'm not a hater. If you want to do someone's homework for them in exchange for some virtual internet points, that's up to you :) it's your time after all. He's bluntly asking someone to spit out some code for him. Does that do anyone a favor? Don't jump to conclusions, I deliberately come off as an a-hole, but everything is for a reason. He didn't even try anything. Had he tried it.. different story.

Comment: It's not my homework! I have tried to solve this problem by myself a lot of time. Now I'm just asking for the help - that it.

Comment: You didn't even **show** what you tried so far, you just asked for the code. You're a member for quite some time here, in 5 years should know how to ask for help. Facts are disproving what you're saying. It's irrelevant at this point because there's always someone who will do work for you, as shown by evidence.

Comment: @N.B. i do like the points, but i actually figured he has something more in mind - he's got almost 1K reputation - he had to earn it doing something. i'm still expecting to hear i'm completely wrong w/ my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's the problem here, so here's how I got it and you can say what did I get wrong. Afterwards, you can edit your question :)

Hence:

```
// this should be given
$d0 = 1.22;
$b = 0.37; 

function dx($x = 0) {
   global $d0, $b;

   return $d0 /exp($b*$x);
}

echo dx(6.74); // d_{6.74}
```